# Проблема отображения навигации Fancybox

Tags: javascript, html, изображения, fancybox, навигация

Здравствуйте. 
Есть блок слайдера с изображениями:

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item">
        <a href="1.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="group">
            <img src="1.jpg" alt="Изображение 1">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="2.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="group">
            <img src="2.jpg" alt="Изображение 2">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="3.jpg" class="fancybox" rel="group">
            <img src="3.jpg" alt="Изображение 3">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Для увеличения изображений по клику прикрутил Fancybox, в котором есть встроенная "фича" отображения количества изображений в стиле точек (dotted navigation), работающая с помощью функций на JS - **addLinks()** и **removeLinks()**:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    nextEffect  : 'fade',
    prevEffect  : 'fade',
    padding     : 0,
    margin      : [15, 15, 40, 15],
    afterLoad   : addLinks,
    beforeClose : removeLinks
});

function addLinks() {
    var list = $("#links");
    if (!list.length) {    
        list = $('<ul id="links">');
        for (var i = 0; i < this.group.length; i++) {
            $('<li data-index="' + i + '"><label></label></li>').click(function() { $.fancybox.jumpto( $(this).data('index'));}).appendTo( list );
        }
        list.appendTo( 'body' );
    }
    list.find('li').removeClass('active').eq( this.index ).addClass('active');
}
function removeLinks() {
    $("#links").remove();    
}
```

Элементы навигации отображаются, но проблема вот в чём: изображения 3, а этих элементов 7. Они кликабельны, изображения переключаются, но повторяются по два-три раза. Также при открытии первого изображения становится активен третий элемент навигации, а не первый. Если я правильно понял, то проблема заключается именно в такой вложенности изображений в разные блоки.

[image: Вместо 3 отображается 7]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом переписать код функции так, чтобы элементы навигации при такой структуре вложенности работали как надо, даже если изображений будет больше.